# File path will not save in db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

INTRO: I'm creating a 'Social network' site. It's more of a learning exercise than a business venture. I have created the simple version of login and registration (without encryption) they use PHPMyadmin and work.

I've created the form and php code to insert/save an image to the server and save the path to phpmyadmin (via sql). The page prints it's successful, however the path does not appear in the database. i've tried millions and now im fully stuck!

```
<?php
session_start();
$db_conx = $_SESSION['con'];
$id = $_SESSION['uid'];

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
          $folder="upload/";
          $suffix= rand();
          $path=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $folder . $suffix . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          $fullpath = $folder.$suffix.$_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
          echo "Stored in: " .$fullpath;  
          if("INSERT INTO *table* (*field*) VALUES ($fullpath)"){
              echo 'Successfull!!';} else {
        echo 'fail';}
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Database cols
[image: database columns]

Comment: change `if("INSERT INTO dbusers (ppl) VALUES ('$fullpath')"){`

Comment: Are you calling `mysql_query` / `mysqli_query` / etc with that SQL?

Comment: You really should be using a [PHP Framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) for this rather than hand-rolling your entire application. What you're producing here is legacy code that's extremely difficult to iterate on and maintain. You're simply stating a database call, not executing it. `if` on a string like that will always be true.

Comment: @andrewsi no I did have at some point during my trials but that was 'mysqli_query("INSERT' and I then realised/remembered thats incorrect.

Comment: If your if statement is just `if ("INSERT INTO...)`, it's always going to return true, because you're effectively just checking to see if that string exists. If you want to add it to the database, you need to pass that string into `mysqli_query()` - why do you think that that's incorrect?

Comment: @andrewsi "For non-DML queries (not INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE), this function is similar to calling mysqli_real_query() followed by either mysqli_use_result() or mysqli_store_result()." Source:- us1.php.net/mysqli_query or have i misunderstood? if so i apologise im shattered

Comment: I go with @andrewsi, you are not executing the query at all! But use escaping / quotes anyway.

Comment: As andrewsi says, your success/fail test isn't a test at all. Normally you would check the return value of `mysqli_query()`. Also about your November 11 21:00 comment, I don't see you calling `mysqli_real_query()` anywhere either...at some point you have to call code that operates on the database. Besides, I just stick with `mysqli_query()` because then I don't have to next run ` mysqli_store_result()` or `mysqli_use_result()`, but that's just me. Are you actually initializing a database connection on another page and storing the resulting link from `mysqli_connect()` in `$_SESSION['con']`?

Comment: It's difficult for me to see the whole picture, but it appears that you're susceptible to SQL injection attacks. From what I gather, one would have to name a file with the injection string, but it seems possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php for more details.

Comment: I sorted it... can't quite remember how, sorry; should've posted and also sorted the sql update. Thanks guys